# VBA ms access remove form filter

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that is filtered using the value chosen in a combox and then pressing a button. It works well.
Then I have another button to remove the filter and the form shows all the values. The latter does not work well, although I have found a slightly odd solution.

If in the on click event of the remove filters button I put:

```
Me.Form.Filter = ""
Me.Form.FilterOn = False
Me.combox22 = Null
```

IT DOES NOT WORK

if in the on click event of the remove filters button I put:

```
    Me.Form.Filter = ""
Me.Form.FilterOn = False
Me.combox22 = Null
Me.Form.Filter = ""
Me.Form.FilterOn = False
Me.combox22 = Null
```

IT WORKS PERFECTLY

Why I have to duplicate the code?

Comment: Try just reversing first two lines in first version. That's how my code is.

Comment: `Me.Form.` is redundant - `Me` *is* the form.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not in your code. I created form and tested it. This works just fine:

```
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
```

Comment: That didn't work for me too. I have to duplicate the code. It is a bug and I suppose it has to do with the version of the Access. I use 2010.

Answer (score 1):

If .FilterON is true, it will ignore your changes to the .filter property.  Set the FilterOn to False first, then Filter to "":

```
Me.FilterOn = False
Me.Filter = ""
```